# If I smash this phone into a million pieces is it secure?

Tags: phone, smartphone, destruction

This phone that I am using has some ***very*** sensitive info on it. I am wondering if it will be secure if I take a hammer and smash it into many pieces, and if I take the pieces and throw them out at various states when I travel will it be unrecoverable?

I am talking about state and government-level security. Not just against petty criminals.

Comment: Whenever someone asks if something is secure or not, it always begs the question 'secure from who/what?'  Something which is secure from one type of threat actor (a criminal, for example) may not be secure from another (A national intelligence organization, for another example.)   Who is the threat in this question?

Comment: @DanLandberg secure from state level organizations.

Comment: I discovered something that some government probably do not want me to have discovered, and I know that it has been logged probably. But if I smash this phone, I hope that the logs will just point to something that doesn't exist anymore (the phone).

Comment: It's going to matter a lot whether the pieces are all the same size.  If the screen breaks into 999,995 pieces and then the rest breaks into very large pieces: motherboard, battery, wireless charging coil, power button, activity LED --- then you have one million pieces but data recovery won't be much challenge to your threats.  (And this is the most likely outcome if using hammer, machete, and rock)

Comment: State/Nation level organisations? Presumably the information exists in your head/memory as well as the phone and might be subjected to extraction using "enhanced interrogation" or outright torture, depending on which government. Should they come looking and you cant hand them a phone to prove the information hasn't been shared further then the proof/evidence would have to come from you.

Comment: @wireghoul So you're possibly referencing the obligatory [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/538/)?

Comment: "throw them out at various states when I travel": Security aside, this sounds like a great holiday plan! :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you smash the phone into tiny pieces and scatter them on different places, the data that only exists on the phone is lost forever.

But not all data resides only on your phone. If any online copy exists (in backups, sync, caches or anything else), that data is still alive and can be recovered.

Comment: Okay this works. The data was only on this phone. And if the phone no longer exists, then I would assume that knowing that this phone was used by me would become moot?

Comment: This depends *entirely* on how small the prices are **of the storage chips**. Breaking apart the case will do nothing.

Comment: By tiny I mean "sand grain sized pieces"...

Answer (score 1):

## If you've smashed it *properly*, most likely secure

For a modern phone, the two biggest factors for future-proof data destruction are:

1. Whether the phone's storage utilized full encryption;
2. Whether the storage medium or chip was properly FUBAR'd.

Full disk encryption [comes by default on iPhones since the iPhone 4](https://appleinsider.com/inside/apple-and-encryption), and became SoC TPM-based (Secure Enclave) since the iPhone 5. If an iPhone is any newer, and had a passcode set, it is reasonable to assume that it uses secure disk encryption.

Android [supported full disk encryption](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/encryption/full-disk) as early as 4.4, [switched to file-based encryption](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/encryption/file-based) in 7.0, and deprecated full-disk encryption in favour of mandated file-based in 10.0. However, implementations varies wildly across models and brands, so take this information with a grain of salt unless you know the specifications of data-at-rest encryption for your specific device. Android devices should only be somewhat reasonably assumed to use sufficiently secure encryption if it is very new, and from a major brand.

In both cases, if the device was securely encrypted, *without easily exploitable vulnerabilities or backdoors*, this is already usually enough to shut out even the most resourceful of attackers like state adversaries.

Now, for the physical medium: to prevent side-channel leaks from any such vulnerabilities or backdoors, shredding or incinerating the physical storage medium is the most secure and fastest option across the industry. Bending or deforming the chip helps, but is usually not "secure"; something industrial-sized will be a lot better than a hammer, unless you've been very methodical.

Effectively all cellphones and smartphones ever made for the commercial market use [Solid State Drives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive), storing the data within persistent semiconductors. The SSD chip itself probably looks something like this:

[image: iPhone 11 Pro Max NVMe chip, Toshiba TSB4236 512GB]

If the disk was properly encrypted, smashing the NVMe chip (the grey one in the example image) into pieces will destroy all hope of recovering the data, *ever*. Even the best modern forensics combined with cryptanalysis attacks won't even start making any headway, and the transistors will begin to lose their storage states within a few years without power, so any theoretical forensics technologies which may apply won't come along before the data is already gone for good. Every single intelligence agency on planet Earth working on it as a joint project will probably still not be able to recover any data whatsoever.

If the disk was **not** properly encrypted, bets are off unless you've either incinerated the chip, or shredded it down to dust. Although there aren't many real-world examples of forensics on destroyed SSDs, you can be certain that it will be insanely impractical to begin to attempt to rebuild the chip at all with sufficiently amounts of destruction, notwithstanding the forensics necessary to recover any data from the storage cells in the first place. And again, the transistors will begin losing their storage states without power, so the window for analysis is somewhat limited.

For your case specifically, since you've been scattering the pieces across various locations, this already increases the difficulty of recovery by an order of magnitude simply by the merit of the pieces being difficult to find, and probably being exposed to weathering. Even in a worst-case scenario (no encryption, less than a dozen pieces) it will likely require at least millions of dollars just to recover a small portion of data.

Most of these suggestions assume a global adversary with vast resources and practically limitless access to latest unknown technologies. Forensics on loose SSD storage cells is extremely, extremely difficult. There are very few cases which would justify this amount of forensic effort to begin with, like if you've stolen all of the CIA's, DoD's, and NSA's top secret files combined since the 1970s and gave it to China. Adapt your threat model according to your needs, and your plausible theoretical adversary.

Comment: _Forensics on loose SSD storage cells is extremely, extremely difficult._ – It's not easy because the FTL's behavior is not revealed by most SSD manufacturers, but I wouldn't go so far as to say that it takes a highly-sophisticated government agency to apply. I've seen EE hobbyists do it.

Answer (score 0):

This would be secure if it was smashed beyond repair, however if you're running any cloud services or google drive has some of the files, or its in any cloud storage in general, it could still be accessed.
For an example, Android and iPhone have cloud storage built in.
So yes as long as its not anywhere on a cloud service or online.